# Kbuntu + MS Arc Touch Mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have read a few posts similar to my question however they all refer to previous versions of Ubuntu and none specific to the KDE spin (if important). I have tried several solutions but none worked (obviously).

I can *pair* the arc touch however I cannot actually physically connect and use it. I do not know if the current version of bluez is still disfunctional here or what. I could really use advice.

Comment: Which solutions have you tried?

Comment: I tried a different graphical as well as I have tried running a previous bluez version. 5.35 I think it was.